# Listing Items and Displaying Data Inline

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

I use asp.net 3.5 and have also begun looking at 3.5 sp1

I like the clean urls that mvc tends to have but use asp.net webforms for my primary development. I normally use a url rewriter in order to accomplish this type stuff. When I say clean urls I mean like /products to get a list of products and /products/Product_One to look at the info about product called Product_One. I've used this on sites where the listing is on one page and when you pick the item it goes to a different page that shows the info about the item selected.

but

I also like the way that the update panel works and changing stuff on screen with out flashing the screen. When I do this I tend to have a list on the left with the different items that are selectable and then have on the left the data about the selected item, then I use an update panel so that when the item on the left is selected it's data shows up on the left without flashing.

I need opinions on what you all think of the two different methods of displaying a list and seeing the item that is selected's data.

1) Which is better in your opinion?

2) What do you all do to display a list and show the data on one of the items?

3) Is there another way of doing this?

4) Is it possible to combine the update panel method and the nice urls? (i.e. change the url to match the url that would get you to the current displayed data even though the update panel was used, and add to the history the new clean url for the current page)

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is [AJAX URL history management](http://quickstarts.asp.net/Futures/ajax/doc/history.aspx) but you will not be able to modify the URL besides the "#" anchor.

At least not without reloading the page.